# How not to pay for waiting for PostgreSQL insert inside an AWS Lambda?

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, psycopg2

I have an AWS Lambda function that does something like this:

```
def handler(payload, context):
    processed = process(payload)
    connection = get_psycopg2_connection_from_pool()
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO mytable (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (%s)" % processed)
    cursor.commit()
    return_connection_to_pool(connection)
```

I can see in the logs that the majority of execution time of this function is spent while waiting for PostgreSQL to perform the INSERT (it takes long because the data is rather large)

How do I avoid paying for the time the function spends while waiting?

As an idea, is it possible to use some kind of async IO based on callbacks? That way the function would return after sending the request and any errors would be handled in the callback?

Comment: Callback will not help at all since your lambda would have to run anyway…

Comment: How large is large?  How long is long? Does the lambda cost more than the database itself?

Comment: 1) **DO NOT do this**: `...VALUES (%s)" % processed`. Use proper parameter passing per [Parameter passing](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries). 2) To potentially speed things up use [Fast Execution Helpers](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#fast-execution-helpers) 3) To speed things up even more use [Copy](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#using-copy-to-and-copy-from) if appropriate.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver, executemany is actually used there, I just wrote that statement with %s as an example

Comment: @jjanes, large is up to 40000 rows. Long is up to 6 seconds. The lambda definetely costs much more than the lambda, but it is serving lots of purposes.

Comment: If you do not provide the actual code you are running then providing an answer is going to be difficult to impossible.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver, the process of INSERT-ion may probably be improved by using COPY or reducing the amount of data, but I am curious whether the cost of waiting for an arbitrary external resource may be optimized.

Comment: 6 seconds for 40000 records seems long. I'm guessing either network lag between where the function is run and database server is or this `processed = process(payload)` is taking time. You should try and get finer detail where the time is being spent.